# SASL authentication in docker zookeeper and kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper, sasl

Can anyone please help in enabling SASL authentication with wurstmeister/zookeeper and wurstmeister/kafka in docker compose? I run these without authentication and everything works fine, but I am not able to setup simple username/password authentication.

```
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    build: ./kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper        
    ports:
      - "9095:9095"
    hostname: kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9095 
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9095
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SASL_PLAINTEXT://kafka:9095
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_OPTS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: PLAIN
      KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN      
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  
      - ./kafka_server_jaas.conf:/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf
```

kafka_server_jaas.conf

```
KafkaServer {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin-secret"
  user_admin="admin-secret";
};

Client {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin-secret"
  user_admin="admin-secret";
};
```

I plan to connect to Kafka inside a docker container that is running Kafkajs on Node.js

Comment: Did you have any luck with this ?

Answer (score 2):

I got SASL authentication working with the `wurstmeister` images with the below config.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
    environment:
      JVMFLAGS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/zookeeper/zookeeper_jaas.conf"
    volumes:
      - ./zookeeper_jaas.conf:/etc/zookeeper/zookeeper_jaas.conf
    ports:
     - 2181:2181
     
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.8.1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9093,EXTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9093,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: 'yes'
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: PLAIN
      KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN
      KAFKA_OPTS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_jaas.conf"
    volumes:
      - ./kafka_server_jaas.conf:/etc/kafka/kafka_jaas.conf
```

**zookeeper_jaas.conf:**

```
Server {
    org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
    user_admin="admin-secret";
};
```

**kafka_server_jaas.conf:**

```
KafkaServer {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin-secret"
  user_admin="admin-secret";
};

Client {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin-secret";
};
```

Needed to set the below additional kafka client properties in the producer/consumer:

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="admin" password="admin-secret";
```

Comment: This does not working for me, getting ERROR SASL authentication failed using login context 'Client' with exception: {} (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Error in authenticating with a Zookeeper Quorum member: the quorum member's saslToken is null.

Comment: Just verified that it still works fine for me. When are you getting this error? If it is from the producer or consumer, they do need to specify the 3 client properties that I have mentioned above in the answer

Comment: It happens during startup. no producer or consumer yet.

Comment: You da man! What a nice cheat sheet.